# How do I achieve a dynamic Annotated String in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How can I achieve texts like this dynamically?
So as i can do something like this `AnnotatedTextComponent(text = "$boldText in the beginning and $redText in the middle", annotatedItems = ($boldText, $redText) )`
[image]

Comment: would probably be achievable using the [AnnotatedString.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder) (with an if statement to check for amount of people that placed a comment)

Comment: Does your app supports multiple languages also?

Answer (score 0):

I have an example which I use in one of my Apps so giving you a short example which you can customize as you wish.

**Preview Output**
[image: preview]

```
data class ParagraphData(
    val text: String,
    val markups: List<Markup> = emptyList()
)

data class Markup(
    val type: MarkupType,
    val start: Int,
    val end: Int,
    val color : Color
)

enum class MarkupType {
    Italic,
    Bold,
}



@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Stack028(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val paragraph = ParagraphData(
        "Hello From Text Paragraph",
        markups = listOf(
            Markup(MarkupType.Bold, start = 0, end = 5, color = Color.Red),
            Markup(MarkupType.Italic, start = 16, end = 25, color = Color.Green
            )
        )
    )

    Paragraph(
        paragraph = paragraph
    )
}


@Composable
private fun Paragraph(paragraph: ParagraphData) {
    val textStyle = getTextAndParagraphStyle()

    val annotatedString = paragraphToAnnotatedString(
        paragraph,
        MaterialTheme.typography
    )
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        text = annotatedString,
        style = textStyle
    )
}

@Composable
private fun getTextAndParagraphStyle(): TextStyle {
    val typography = MaterialTheme.typography
    return  typography.bodyLarge.copy(lineHeight = 28.sp)
}

private fun paragraphToAnnotatedString(
    paragraph: ParagraphData,
    typography: Typography,
): AnnotatedString {
    val styles: List<AnnotatedString.Range<SpanStyle>> = paragraph.markups
        .map { it.toAnnotatedStringItem(typography) }
    return AnnotatedString(text = paragraph.text, spanStyles = styles)
}

fun Markup.toAnnotatedStringItem(
    typography: Typography,
): AnnotatedString.Range<SpanStyle> {
    return when (this.type) {
        MarkupType.Italic -> {
            AnnotatedString.Range(
                typography.bodyLarge.copy(fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic, color = color).toSpanStyle(),
                start,
                end
            )
        }
        MarkupType.Bold -> {
            AnnotatedString.Range(
                typography.bodyLarge.copy(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = color).toSpanStyle(),
                start,
                end
            )
        }

    }
}
```