How I can apply multiple formats and styles based on certains characters using Jetpack Compose?
I'm migrating my code to Jetpack Compose and I can't find a way to apply multiple styles based on some characters in the content.
For example, starting from this text:
 "℣¦Cantaré eternamente las misericordias del Señor, ≀anunciaré tu
 fidelidad por todas las edades. ≀Porque dijiste: «La misericordia es
 un edificio eterno», ≀más que el cielo has afianzado tu fidelidad.
 ℟§℣¦«Sellé una alianza con mi elegido, ≀jurando a David, mi siervo:
 ≀Te fundaré un linaje perpetuo, ≀edificaré tu trono para todas las
 edades». ℟§℣¦Él me invocará: “Tú eres mi padre, ≀mi Dios, mi Roca
 salvadora”. ≀Le mantendré eternamente mi favor, ≀y mi alianza con él
 será estable. ℟"

I would need to apply the following:

Replace all ℣ or all ℟ by the same character, but with another color.
Replace all ¦ by 4 withe spaces or one tabulation.
Replace all ≀ by one line break and 4 withe spaces or one tabulation.
Replace all § by double line break (or one begin of paragraph)

The final result will be something like that:

Before Compose I could achieve this using replace, with this code:
fun getFormato(sOrigen: String): String {
    return sOrigen
        .replace("§", BRS)
        .replace("~", BR)
        .replace("¦", NBSP_4)
        .replace("℟", toRedFont("℟."))
        .replace("℣", toRedFont("℣."))
}

The values of the constants in .replace are:
const val BRS = "<br /><br />"
const val BR = "<br />"
const val NBSP_4 = " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"

And the method for red font:
fun toRedFont(s: String?): String {
        return String.format("<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>", redCode, s)
}

How could I apply those styles and/or formats in Compose-based code?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77890288/how-do-i-achieve-a-dynamic-annotated-string-in-jetpack-compose

For colors and certain styles, you don't need to use hacky ways (even on Views) like HTML to achieve what you want and you can use Spannable and in Compose you can use AnnotatedString.

@Yamin I understand that, but is it possible to replace a character with a SpanStyle for example?

Based on your requirements, here is a method to transform the text using AnnotatedString:
private fun transformText(text: String) = buildAnnotatedString {
    text.forEach { c ->
        when (c) {
            '℣', '℟' -> withStyle(SpanStyle(color = Color.Red)) { append(c) }
            '¦' -> append("\t")
            '≀' -> append("\n\t")
            '§' -> append("\n\n")
            else -> append(c)
        }
    }
}

Demo :
@Composable
fun App() {
val inputText = "℣¦Cantaré eternamente las misericordias del Señor, ≀anunciaré tu" +
     " fidelidad por todas las edades. ≀Porque dijiste: «La misericordia es" +
     " un edificio eterno», ≀más que el cielo has afianzado tu fidelidad." +
     " ℟§℣¦«Sellé una alianza con mi elegido, ≀jurando a David, mi siervo:" +
     " ≀Te fundaré un linaje perpetuo, ≀edificaré tu trono para todas las" +
     " edades». ℟§℣¦Él me invocará: “Tú eres mi padre, ≀mi Dios, mi Roca" +
     " salvadora”. ≀Le mantendré eternamente mi favor, ≀y mi alianza con él" +
     " será estable. ℟"
    
    val transformedText = transformText(inputText)
    Text(text = transformedText)
}


